# vmware network interface not detected

Tags: 14.04, networking, virtualization, vmware, e1000

I installed ubuntu server 14.04 LTS on a virtual machine (vmware, win host). The VM has internet access (given a port-id, adaptertype E1000E and a MAC). Sadly ubuntu was not able to detect the device automatically.

`ifconfig -a` shows only the loop back interface but lspci prints the following Ethernet controller:

> 0b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection

How can create a proper eth0 interface?

The `/etc/network/interfaces` file contains only a `lo` interface so I tried to create a eth0. The VM-Host provided a the IP, net mask, gateway settings. So I added the following lines to my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address ....
gateway ....
netmask ....
```

Then I tried to force these settings by calling `/etc/init.d/networking restart` but without success.

The devices uses the e1000e Kernel-Module. I already tried to remove and load it again, but I always get the error, that it's busy.

**UPDATE:**
The network settings for the vm look like this:

[image]

So there is no network connection, but the device status is connected. I used Windows on the same VM before and there the internet connection worked out-of-the-box. How can access such a network connection with ubuntu?

- All commands in `var/log/boot.log` pass with status [OK]
- `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i eth` is empty
- `dmesg | grep -i etc` is also empty

**UPDATE2:**

It seems like the e1000e interface support is not quite good, so I asked the vm-admin to change the interface type to vmxnet3. Now the `ifconfig -a` returns two different interfaces (lo and a new `ens192`).

> dmesg | grep vmxnet3

[image]

Then I added the following lines to my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto ens192
iface ens192 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask x.x.x.x
    network x.x.x.x
    broadcast x.x.x.x
    dns-nameservers x.x.x.x
    dns-search example.com
    gateway x.x.x.x
```

... and restarted the service per `/etc/init.d/networking restart`. But the interface is not connected:

> ping google.com

and

> ping 193.170.141.212

return "Destination Host unreachable"

Comment: check "cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules"

Comment: @PKumar this file does not exists. There is only a README within `/etc/udev/rules.d/`.

Comment: ok no issue, try to run "ifconfig eth0 up" then check "ifconfig -a"

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, there is no eth0 (just the loopback interface) so the command returns "eth0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device".

Comment: try "ifconfig eth1 up"  or "ifconfig eth2 up" if not increment the eth number

Comment: @PKumar I tried it up to eth7 without success. Should the `/etc/network/interfaces` file contain something except the lo-interface? I tried to add a eth0 interface with my settings (I have a static ip, netmask and gateway) but I am not able to apply these changes. A `/etc/init.d/networks restart` does not change the output of the `ifconfig -a`

Comment: @NaN In a clean new install of 14.04 over VMWare 12, `/etc/network/interfaces` contains only `lo`, `ifconfig` does show `eth0`, and `lspci` is similar to what you have.  I've got to assume that something went incorrectly for you during the setup of Ubuntu.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I installed it multiple times (ubuntu server 14.04 and 15.10), but I always get the error that no network device was found.

Comment: Weird.  I'm afraid I don't have an answer for this one

Comment: Can you append the output of `dmesg | grep -i eth` to your question?

Comment: @CharlesGreen The output of this command is empty!

Comment: K - that would mean that the kernel never sees the ethernet adaptor.  Can you examine `/var/log/boot.log`for error messages, and add the output of  `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i eth`

Comment: @CharlesGreen all commands in boot.log passed (with status [OK]). syslog does not contain any messages containing eth.

Comment: The little bit in the added image with the yellow triangle...  I think it is trying to tell me something....  [This link](https://communities.vmware.com/message/1388245) and [this link](http://heelpbook.altervista.org/2015/vcenter-server-permissions-to-modify-virtual-machine-network-settings/) refer to that error message, on the host computer side.

Comment: @CharlesGreen now my interface works, but there is no internet connection. I am able to ping my own ip/hostnames but all other ips do not respond.

Comment: K - can you append the output of  `ifconfig` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` to your post?

Comment: Now it works! the admins had to re-enable network connection of the vm after the adapter type change (from e1000e to vmxnet3).

Comment: Hi Nan, could you please remove the solution from the question and add it as (accepted) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use e1000 on Ubuntu. Neither vmxnet3 or e1000e are fully supported or work well with NAT*

(*)*at least for OP*

Comment: Although the question is highly upvoted, no upvotes for this answer. @Robert [Please see me in chat?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room)