# Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 ESXi trashed network card

Tags: networking, upgrade, vmware

Good afternoon, all!

While on a short holiday a colleague upgraded an Ubuntu 14.04 VM to 16.04. The machine is running on ESXi 5.5. After the upgrade, the VM can't see the E1000 network card, but the VM settings show the card allocated from ESXi.  The /etc/network/interfaces file is also unchanged.

AFAIK, the upgrade shouldn't have bashed the plain vanilla ethernet card presented by ESXi.

Anyone run into a similar issue?

Thanks!

Comment: How is networking set up in the 16.04 VM? Bridged, perhaps?

Comment: My colleague found the answer - the network adapter name in 16.04 gets changed from eth0 to ens33.  Change the name in /etc/network/interfaces and we were back in business.   Thanks to all for looking!

Comment: Does this duplicate the issue in the below post? https://askubuntu.com/questions/697540/vmware-network-interface-not-detected It looks like the Intel/Gigabit 1000e network is not fully supported. Try the VMXnet3 interface type instead.